# Node.js: cannot call method 'use' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to learn node.js and I'm getting this error.

```
app.use(morgan('dev')); //log request to console
TypeError: Cannot call method 'use' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/root/authproject/server.js:21:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:901:3
```

What could be causing it?

Comment: Like the error says: `app` is undefined. You really need to add more of your code for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need some code like this to setup express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

And you'll need to import `morgan` similarly. I'm presume you're copying the code from somewhere - perhaps it's not a complete example?